# How can you limit srcset on a single type of page?

Tags: functions, images, html

It turns out that different browsers handle how they load images with srcset slightly differently and network speed is of vital importance for me.

I don't want to globally limit srcset, but I want to make sure that there are no srcsets over a certain width only on posts.

Is this possible with code?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example for filtering out sizes above set limit from the `srcset` attribute on certain post type. This works for featured image and images added to the post content with Gutenberg. (Tested on Twenty Twenty theme).

```
function filter_wp_calculate_image_srcset( $sources, $size_array, $image_src, $image_meta, $attachment_id ) {
    global $post;
    if ( $post && 'post' === $post->post_type ) {
        $max_size = 600; // change as needed
        // var_dump($sources);
        foreach ($sources as $size => $image) {
            if ( $size > $max_size ) {
                unset($sources[$size]);
            }
        }
        // var_dump($sources);
    }
    return $sources;
}
add_filter( 'wp_calculate_image_srcset', 'filter_wp_calculate_image_srcset', 11, 5 );
```

Filter docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_calculate_image_srcset/